# windows programming , how to create a function in dll which can take all datatypes as input?

Tags: c++, windows, function

I want a common function which can take any data type as a argument and return result in that data type only. How to implement this via dll.

Comment: Like any other templated function?

Comment: You are talking about generic functions of the form Class<T> for c++ look for information about templates. http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/ (scroll to about half -way)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you would like to export in the dll a templated function, without specifying it's type.

You cannot do that because templates are resolved at compile time (so when the code is generated). As mentioned by @MSlaters you cannot have an infinitely big template.

If you have a predefined number of data types, you can force instantiate each of them in your dll code in order to have them exposed.

If you want to make the most generic thing possible , you can only have

```
void* getResult (void* inputParameter)
```

But unfortunately, you won't know how the memory is mapped for the object (so less of gain, more of a pain if you'd ask me).

Comment: This sort of function can be useful if the pointer is only passing through; it's classically used for things like `pthread_create`, for example, where the pointer ends up as an argument to a call-back.

Comment: And just a question of wording: I think you mean an infinite number of instantiations of a template (one instantiation for all possible types, including those yet to be written), and not an infinitely big template.  The sources for an infinitely big template won't fit on any disk.

Answer (score 0):

Not. A DLL contains compiled code, in particular the `return` statements. Since you support an inifinite number of types with an infinite number of return statements, the DLL would be infinitely big.